# Verilog: Converting BCD (or binary) to BCH

Tags: verilog

I'm looking to code a BCD (or binary) to binary-coded hexadecimal which will be then converted to 7-segment display codes and sent serially to a latched shift register to drive the display. It's for a 16-bit microprocessor, that outputs signed 16-bit number.

I've already successfully coded and fully tested a binary to BCD converter using the ***shift and add 3*** algorithm. The number is converted to positive if negative and a sign flag is set to notate sign. Most design example I saw on the internet were combinatorial. I took a sequential approach to it, and takes around 35 clock cycles to do so.

My question is, is there a way to convert the BCD I have to BCH? Or perhaps it would be easier to convert the binary to BCH. Whichever way is more feasible. Performance is not an issue. Is there an existing algorithm to do so?

I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use a look up table.  Have an input to your case statement be your BCD digit, and the output be your BCH digit.  Both will be 4 bits wide guaranteed, so you can parse your BCD digits one at a time and each one will produce a 4 bit output.

Converting from Binary to BCD is harder because you need to use a double dabble algorithm (as you have found out).  But once it's in BCD you shouldn't have a problem going to BCH.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. BCD is a subset of BCH, so there is no possible function that would give me the BCH equivalent of a BCD number without looking at the previous digit because BCD would carry over anything above 9. Could you please elaborate on how such a look up table would work? Apologies if I misunderstood you. Also, I couldn't possible look up for all explicit states since there are 65,536 possible states.

Comment: I'm certain I tagged you in the previous comment @Russell. Apologies.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood you. You meant to convert directly from binary to hex, I believe this does work. I don't think it's possible from BCD to BCH this way with a look up.